# Minecraft Mods- Not Working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Okay, so I looked up how to install mods. I want to get the Biomes O Plenty so that it works in minecraft. I did absolutely **everything** the instructions from three different sites told me to do and triple checked to make sure it was done. The thing is, when I run Minecraft, the mod won't work! I have Minecraft version 1.7.10 and the mod I downloaded is for that version of Minecraft. I also have Windows 7. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, if I'm doing anything wrong. I don't know how to get it so that when I play the game, it will show up with the mod working.

Comment: Current version of the `Biomes O' Plenty` is 1.6.4, no way you can get it working with 1.7.10.

Comment: Have you installed Forge Mod Loader for 1.7.10?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 5):

Biomes O plenty is a mod that alters the generation of the minecraft world.

To use it after installing it you have to create a new world, go to options and set the World type to "Biomes O plenty".